# I am getting an error while using the properties of interface declared in my code. Why am I getting the error even though the code is correct?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Here in this code I have declared an interface labelled Row. I have used the properties further in the code but it throws an error.

Code-

```
import { ServerRespond } from './DataStreamer';

export interface Row {
  price_abc: number,
  price_def: number,
  ratio: number,
  timestamp: Date,
  upper_bound: number,
  lower_bound: number,
  trigger_alert: number | undefined,
}


export class DataManipulator {
  static generateRow(serverResponds: ServerRespond[]): Row[] {
    const priceABC = (serverResponds[0].top_ask.price + serverResponds[0].top_bid.price) / 2;
    const priceDEF = (serverResponds[1].top_ask.price + serverResponds[1].top_ask.price) / 2;
    const ratio = priceABC / priceDEF;
    const upperBound = 1 + 0.05;
    const lowerBound = 1 + 0.05;
    return {
        price_abc: priceABC,
        price_def: priceDEF,
        ratio,
        timestamp: serverResponds[0].timestamp > serverResponds[1].timestamp ?
          serverResponds[0].timestamp : serverResponds[1].timestamp,
        upper_bound: upperBound,
        lower_bound: lowerBound,
        trigger_alert: (ratio > upperBound || ratio < lowerBound) ? ratio : undefined,
      };
  }
}
```

Error-

```
Type error: Type '{ price_abc: number; price_def: number; ratio: number; timestamp: Date; upper_bound: number; lower_bound: number; trigger_alert: number | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'Row[]'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'price_abc' does not exist in type 'Row[]'.  TS2322
```

- I have tried uninstalling and then installing typescript again.
- I have tried installing the node modules that are required several times.

I am not able to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to return an array **(Row[])** (The [] indicate that you want to return an array of that object) but you are only returning a single object, you have to adjust to that.
Either like this (where you return just the row):

```
 static generateRow(serverResponds: ServerRespond[]): Row { // The [] are removed so you only return a single object
    const priceABC = (serverResponds[0].top_ask.price + serverResponds[0].top_bid.price) / 2;
    const priceDEF = (serverResponds[1].top_ask.price + serverResponds[1].top_ask.price) / 2;
    const ratio = priceABC / priceDEF;
    const upperBound = 1 + 0.05;
    const lowerBound = 1 + 0.05;
    return {
        price_abc: priceABC,
        price_def: priceDEF,
        ratio,
        timestamp: serverResponds[0].timestamp > serverResponds[1].timestamp ?
          serverResponds[0].timestamp : serverResponds[1].timestamp,
        upper_bound: upperBound,
        lower_bound: lowerBound,
        trigger_alert: (ratio > upperBound || ratio < lowerBound) ? ratio : undefined,
      };
  }
```

Either like this (where you return just the array of rows):

```
 static generateRow(serverResponds: ServerRespond[]): Row[] {
    const priceABC = (serverResponds[0].top_ask.price + serverResponds[0].top_bid.price) / 2;
    const priceDEF = (serverResponds[1].top_ask.price + serverResponds[1].top_ask.price) / 2;
    const ratio = priceABC / priceDEF;
    const upperBound = 1 + 0.05;
    const lowerBound = 1 + 0.05;
    return [{ // Here is the array wrapper around so you return an array with one entry
        price_abc: priceABC,
        price_def: priceDEF,
        ratio,
        timestamp: serverResponds[0].timestamp > serverResponds[1].timestamp ?
          serverResponds[0].timestamp : serverResponds[1].timestamp,
        upper_bound: upperBound,
        lower_bound: lowerBound,
        trigger_alert: (ratio > upperBound || ratio < lowerBound) ? ratio : undefined,
      }]; // And here with ] you close the array
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are specifying that the function is returning `Row[]` `[Row, Row, Row]` when in fact it is returning `Row` `{price_abc: ''...}`. So you should adjust your function to the following interface:

`static generateRow(serverResponds: ServerRespond[]): Row {...`

Instead of `Row[]`

Comment: Got it!! Thank you :)